# Buttons not showing on landscape in sencha touch apps

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have around 12 buttons on my main view,This shows fine{tested on device} 
    on portrait orientation  but only 5 buttons are showing on the landscape orientation,,
    can someone please   tell how to solve this?

Comment: Since the screen dimensions are getting changed, some of the buttons are going out of the screen. You have to play with css properties to render it according to the device orientation. Ext.device.Orientation will help to know when the device orientation is changed.

Comment: Or make you panel scrollable.